# typedef enum values used without initialization

Tags: c

I have created a `typedef enum` for my app's error code.
Where should i put it? 
What is the best way for all the files in the project to recognize it?

e.g.

```
typedef enum error_Codes{
ERROR1,
ERROR2,
...
}APP_ERRORS;
```

i want to use it in ALL my .c files as a print in this manner:

```
iprintf("YOU HAVE ENCOUNTERED ERROR %d", ERROR1);
```

Do i need to initialize a member of the type APP_ERRORS in all my files?
is there a better way?

Comment: Have you heard about [`#include`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/preprocessor/include) and *header files*? And please do some research about [*translation units*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)).

Comment: What do you mean by "*Do i need to initialize a member of the type APP_ERRORS in all my files?*"?

Comment: The answer to your question: put it where it makes sense in your design. You are essentially asking _us_ how _your_ program is designed. Might want to read up on basic design methods with OO.

Comment: ...the answers are ok; just an addition - NO, you don't need to "initialize a member of the type APP_ERRORS"; more, you don't even need a typedef, but it can be handy if you want variables or formal parameters of that type.

Comment: I have created the typedef in an .h file, now, which files can "understand"  it's possible values ( ERROR1, ERROR2..) and how , i have never created a memeber of this type in any of the files?

Answer (score 1):

I'd say the best way is to have it in an h file that you include in your c files.

This way, if you modify a value in your enum, changes will be applied in all c files.

Answer (score 0):

It is common use to put enumerations into your header files `.h` (only once). header files you will add like this in your `.c`:

```
#include "my_header.h"
```

You don't need to assign value to an enum but it will start from `0` and be incremented by `1`each time you add an enumeration:

```
typedef enum error_Codes{
ERROR1, // = 0
ERROR2, // = 1
...     // = ERROR2+1 etc etc
}APP_ERRORS;
```

If you want this enum to be negative, you have to assign some values to it.

However, it is advised to assign value to your enum for readability.